# angular-ui modal is not initially hidden

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-modal

I'm following this [angular recipes page](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/displaying-a-modal-dialog.html) for adding a modal dialog to my ui.  It suggests the following markup, which I've added to one of my views.

```
... html for my view is here ...
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>
<div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
      ... etc, from the recipe doc
</div>
```

What I want to see is my view, plus an "Open Modal" button on the bottom and nothing else.  What I see instead is the button and the content of the modal already visible on the page.

The very next words in the recipe doc are:

> Note that even though we don’t specify it explicitly the modal dialog
>   is hidden initially via the modal attribute. The controller only
>   handles the button click and the showModal value used by the modal
>   attribute.

Why is my modal mark up initially visible on the page?  I think I have installed angular-ui properly... in my index.html:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

And in my app JS:

```
angular.module('MonteAdmin', [
    ...
    'ui.bootstrap',
    ...
  ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That recipes page is likely out of date. At the time of the writing it might have been possible to pass a variable `showModal` to the `modal` directive to reveal or hide it. In your controller, you would have been able to show the modal by setting the scope variable `showModal` to true or false:

```
$scope.showModal = false;

$scope.open = function() {
  $scope.showModal = true;
}
```

The current version does not work that way. You will have much better experience if you read the official documentation for the library at [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal)

If you are using the latest version of the library, the directive is no longer `modal` but `uib-modal`. In addition, you have a bit more work to do to implement your modal.

Modal markup should be in a script tag, with a type set to `text/ng-template` as per the official example:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="stackedModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-{{name}}">The {{name}} modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-{{name}}">
        Having multiple modals open at once is probably bad UX but it's technically possible.
    </div>
</script>
```

To actually open the modal, your button click should trigger the following example function:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
  ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
  ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  size: size,
  appendTo: parentElem,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $ctrl.items;
    }
  }
});
```

You must also define a controller for the modal, itself:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = items;
  $ctrl.selected = {
    item: $ctrl.items[0]
  };

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

All of this code is found on the official documentation for Angular UI Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this also, and even though I defined the controller, it resulted in an error like null is not a function.  I also didn't know how to supply the correct path to the view.  But I will try this again carefully in a couple hours and get back.  Maybe I flubbed something else.  It's good to know at least which thing i should work on getting to work, so thanks for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct stuff.  I find it absurdly complex to put up a simple "are you sure" interface, but I managed to make it work.

Comment: I know how you feel. It seems like a lot for a simple modal, but it is clean, concise, and done the angular way. Compare that to the tangled mess that a standard Bootstrap modal can become.